# How can I retrieve a nested object property in a helper function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create a helper function to render an image path, based on a certain crop type.

From GraphQL I have in `image` object and inside a `crops` object with `type` and `url`:

```
image {
 crops {
  type
  url         
 }
}
```

Now I find the url (based on crop type) like:

```
<Image imageUrl={image.crops.find((crop) => crop.type === CropType.small).url} />
```

I want to create a function for this:

```
const generateCropType = (value) => {
  switch (value) {
    case 'small':
      return image.crops.find((crop) => crop.url === CropType.Small).path;
    case 'large':
      return image.crops.find((crop) => crop.type === CropType.Large).path;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

So I can somehow use it like:

```
<Image imageUrl={generateCrop(small)} />
```

The function argument is now `value`, which I need for the function. But I also have to pass the `image` prop to the function. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Yeah I know but what is best title to to summarize this question, like you changed it?

Comment: Seems like the title I gave is still accurate. I think you're trying way too hard. Look into dot notation.

Comment: No my code is correct, I use TypeScript (and React). I only don't understand how to create this helper function using `value` as argument but also pass my `data: Prop` to this function and still be able to use helper function like `generateCrop(small)`? Thanks